# Hide Input in a custom textbox Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, textbox, passwords

I am using a custom theme which includes a Textbox, and I want to use this to get a password input.

In order to do do that I want the input to be hidden like a regular password input. In a normal textbox I would use the password char option but this one doesn't have it. Can I make the option myself?

Comment: Can't you create a property in your custom control that allows to set the PasswordChar of the inner TextBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this custom control class inherits the TextBox class, it should also inherit the password character behavior. Have you tried setting it even though you don't "see" it as an option?

If this class was built from scratch (not inherited fromTextBox), you can manually create the effect of a password character by modifying one of its keyboard events (e.g. `KeyPress`) or `TextChanged`, if that exists. Your will need to declare a variable for the password, update it appropriately as the user types, and then change the Text of your custom control to a string of password characters the same length as your variable.

If you still can't get your control working, please post the code for the custom class, what you have tried, and the specific problems you encounter when you try each approach.